# How can an aircraft owner/operator track unauthorized flights?

Tags: security

Is there a product or some other way to track an aircraft's use, even if the pilot doesn't file an IFR flight plan, to let the owner know if it's used without authorization?

Comment: [Spot Trace](http://www.findmespot.com/en/index.php?cid=128)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a site that tracks all flights?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26491/is-there-a-site-that-tracks-all-flights)

Comment: I'm curious about what your situation is where it's easier to monitor a plane with online flight tracking than old fashioned security measures like door locks or a closed hangar.

Comment: Yes, its called a Hobbs meter or tach timer.

Comment: There are security devices like Securaplane which can keep track of airplanes, and set off alarms under certain conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is off topic, we already have [a question about keeping planes from being stolen](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9005/1696).

Comment: @fooot I'd say because this is more of a product recommendation than a generalization about how to keep them from getting stolen.

Comment: I hate it when the kids sneak the Cherokee out of the garage at night for a joy ride... ;)

Comment: @RonBeyer -  I think this is only a product recommendation question if there's one method/product to track unauthorized use of airplanes, but I suspect that there is more than one mehod and many products, so an answer can be generic enough to not become a product recommendation.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind would be one of several GPS based fleet vehicle tracking systems. Such a solution would be an appropriate application for a fleet of aircraft, but would probably be cost prohibitive for only one or a few aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

The owner could do regular checks of the aircraft's Hobbs meter, and if the times don't match what the log is saying, then there could be some red flags being thrown.

If someone it out to deceive, I'm sure they could get around this, but maybe then, the problem is giving access of expensive equipment to people who aren't trustworthy.

There are GPS tracking systems that could keep a movement log in memory.